# How to serialize a foreign key from the same model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this model:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    partner = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
```

And in my serializer I have this:

```
class PlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    partner = PlayerSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'partner')
```

But of course this returns an error saying *PlayerSerializer* is not defined.

How do I serialize the foreign key.

I am using Django with REST API. Django 1.10 and python 3.6.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `depth = 1` in Meta, as below

```
class PlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'partner')
        depth = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [`depth`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) option instead:

```
class PlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'partner')
        depth = 1
```